# How to calculate VF queue index value in DPDK Flow Bifurcation Configuration?

Tags: dpdk

Can anyone help to calculate $queue_index_in_VF below.

```
ethtool -N eth1 flow-type udp4 src-ip 192.0.2.2 dst-ip 198.51.100.2 action $queue_index_in_VF0
ethtool -N eth1 flow-type udp4 src-ip 192.1.2.2 dst-ip 198.50.100.2 action $queue_index_in_VF1
```

Where:

`$queue_index_in_VFn`: Bits 39:32 of the variable defines VF id + 1; the lower 32 bits indicates the queue index of the VF. Thus:

```
$queue_index_in_VF0 = (0x1 & 0xFF) << 32 + [queue index].

$queue_index_in_VF1 = (0x2 & 0xFF) << 32 + [queue index].
```

[image: values]

NI = Intel® Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X520

Comment: Hi @Casin, since you are using ixgbe PMD for X520 the queue index calculation you shared looks ok. Can you please tell me the error you are facing? If logs are present please share? or run the application with `--log-level=pmd,8`

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese, as a command I am using 
 `#ethtool -N eth1 flow-type ip4 src-ip 192.0.2.2 dst-ip 198.51.100.2 action 0`
but I am not sure if that 0 is correct because I dont know what is my VF ID and Queue index. I get ` rmgr: Cannot insert RX class rule: Invalid argument` when I execute command

Comment: Also I am writing the interface names:
`0000:04:10.0 '82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbevf `   
                                                 `0000:04:00.0 'Ethernet 10G 2P X520 Adapter' if=p3p1 drv=ixgbe unused=igb_uio`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem I had, it was not about action or queue ID etc.
There are many parameters available in:

```
#ethtool --show-features eth1
```

In my case `rx-all` was off. So I execute:

```
# ethtool -K eth1 rx-all on
```

and after I have managed to add the rule:

```
# ethtool -N eth1 flow-type ip4 src-ip 192.0.2.2 dst-ip 198.51.100.2 action 1

Added rule with ID 2045

# ethtool --show-ntuple eth1

4 RX rings available Total 1 rules

Filter: 2045
        Rule Type: Raw IPv4
        Src IP addr: 192.0.2.2 mask: 0.0.0.0
        Dest IP addr: 198.51.100.2 mask: 0.0.0.0
        TOS: 0x0 mask: 0xff
        Protocol: 0 mask: 0xff
        L4 bytes: 0x0 mask: 0xffffffff
        VLAN EtherType: 0x0 mask: 0xffff
        VLAN: 0x0 mask: 0xffff
        User-defined: 0x0 mask: 0xffffffffffffffff
        Action: Direct to queue 1
```

Comment: cheers, looks like `ethtool -K eth1 rx-all on` is made ti work